# using like operand

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2007

i have this sql query

```
"select * from table where name like ?"
```

but I want it to work as

```
"select * from table where name like ?*  "
```

what is the query please

I am using access with c#

Comment: If you mean what is the wildcard, it is likely to be %, not *

Comment: and that % should be in your parameter not directly in query like '%you%'

Comment: This is not true. The Access wildcard is different from other SQL engines. It IS an asterisks (*).

Comment: @Brad In MS Access itself using DAO in standard mode, then the wildcard is *, outside of MS Access, using Alike keyword or ANSI 92 mode, it is %

Comment: Can you please add your C# code?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `*` to your parameter. I.e., instead of

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", searchValue);
```

use

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", searchValue + "*");
```

Keep your SQL as it is.

If you want to do a wildcard search (instead of a "literal `*`"), note that ADO.NET uses `%`, not `*`:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", searchValue + "%");
```

Comment: I am using dataset and my queries is written inside every table adapter  so i don't send Parameters 
So I need valid SQl statement to do that Please